# Speed, distance and time calculator

Tags: c++, optimization, object-oriented

This is a speed distance and time calculator - the comments should explain most of the odd looking code if there is any. I am looking for suggestions to improve the efficiency of the program and how better to structure it - is my approach the best from a 'best practices', efficiency and OOP point of view.

So, specifically:

- How might I improve to fit in with common best practices?
- I this the most efficient method and structure?
- Could I add or improve functions so I could more easily add features like unit conversions?

I don't want to lose any functionality. The current program calculates speed distance and time as well as showing all working which adds quite a lot of strings to store information. I am still looking to improve these parts as well.

The main reason I am asking, is to avoid bad practices and find better ways of doing what I'm doing. I am a C++ beginner but I know quite a lot.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::string;
using std::endl;
using std::ostringstream;

class Math
{ // Math Class
public:
    ostringstream s;

    // SPEED DISTANCE AND TIME CALCULATION
    double calcSpeed(double distance, double time, string& formula) // SPEED ~ Variable formula passed to the ufnction will be redefined
    {
        s << distance << " / " << time; // Adding numbers to string
        formula = s.str(); // Converting s to formula of type string
        return distance / time; // Returns result of function
    }
    double calcDistance(double speed, double time, string& formula) // DISTANCE
    {
        s << speed << " * " << time;
        formula = s.str();
        return speed * time;
    }
    double calcTime(double speed, double distance, string& formula) // TIME
    {
        s << distance << " / " << speed;
        formula = s.str();
        return distance / speed;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Math math; // Creates object of Math class to be used to access members

    double firstvalue, secondvalue, result; // Numbers used for conditions and working
    int chosenCalc = 1;

    string chosenCalcStr = "speed"; // Strings used for working
    string firstParam, secondParam;
    string formula;
    string intform;

    bool quit = false;

    typedef double (Math::*FuncChosen)(double first, double second, string& third); // Typedef gives access to a function which can change if it has same parameter and return types

    FuncChosen p = &Math::calcSpeed; // p's default value

    /* Welcome Message */
    printf("If you have both other variables in the triangle you can calculate any element. Speed, distance or time.\n");
    printf("The answer given will be in the same units that you entered - if you entered m/s for speed, time will be in seconds etc.\n");

    /* While user enters something other than 4*/
    while (chosenCalc != 4 && !quit) // While user does not want to quit
    {
        printf("Enter 1 if you want to calculate speed, 2 for distance, 3 for time and 4 to exit.\n> ");
        cin >> chosenCalc;

        if (chosenCalc == 4)
        {
            quit = true;
            return 0;
        }

        /* Conditions */

        switch (chosenCalc) {
            case 1:
                p = &Math::calcSpeed; // Redefines p to explicit function at runtime according to conditions
                firstParam = "distance"; // Explanation strings
                secondParam = "time";
                formula = "Speed = distance / time";
                chosenCalcStr = "Speed"; // Type in formula calculated
                break;
            case 2:
                p = &Math::calcDistance;
                firstParam = "speed";
                secondParam = "time";
                formula = "Distance = Speed * time";
                chosenCalcStr = "Distance";
                break;
            case 3:
                p = &Math::calcTime;
                firstParam = "speed";
                secondParam = "distance";
                formula = "Time = distance / speed";
                chosenCalcStr = "Time";
                break;
        }

        /* User Input */

        cout << "\nPlease enter the value for " << firstParam << ".\n> ";
        cin >> firstvalue;
        cout << "Please enter the value for " << secondParam << ".\n> ";
        cin >> secondvalue;
        cout << "\n";

        result = (math.*p)(firstvalue, secondvalue, intform); // Double result = return value of chosen function **NON EXPLICIT (changes at runtime)** math is used as object to access public members

        if (chosenCalc != 1) { cout << "Speed = distance / time\n";} // Print formula - We don't want to print out sum twice unless we are not calculating speed and wnat general formula
        cout << formula << "\n"; // Print adjusted formula
        cout << chosenCalcStr << " = " << intform << "\n"; // Print numbers in formula
        cout << chosenCalcStr << " = " << result << "\n\n"; // Print result

        /* END */
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you got a good grasp of the basic concepts in C++. Good for you! I assume that you are writing C++03. Here is what I suggest that you change to make the code more clear:

- Your `Math` class should be a namespace. Currently, `Math` only has a single member variable, `ostringstream s`, which is shared between the various `calc` functions. This implies that *subsequent* calls to any `calc` functions will simply append to whatever is already in `s`. E.g.,

  ```
  Math math;

  std::string test1, test2, test3;
  math.calcTime(1.0, 0.9, test1);
  math.calcTime(2.0, 0.8, test2);
  math.calcTime(3.0, 0.7, test3);

  std::cout << "test1: " << test1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "test2: " << test2 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "test3: " << test3 << std::endl;
  ```

  This will actually output

  ```
  test1: 0.9 / 1
  test2: 0.9 / 10.8 / 2
  test3: 0.9 / 10.8 / 20.7 / 3
  ```

  which is probably not what you want. So, I suggest that you convert `Math` into a namespace and define `ostringstream s` locally in each `calc` function.
- You're using both `std::cout` and `printf`. Stick to one of them. Since you are already invested in string streams, I suggest the former.
- The `quit` variable is redundant. You're already returning from `main` when `chosenCalc == 4` is true. Speaking of which, I suggest that you get in the habit of writing `4 == chosenCalc` instead. This way, you will get a nice compiler error if you accidentally write `4 = chosenCalc`.
- You're using a `switch` statement. Excellent! Stick to it. Add a `case 4` instead of having the `if(chosenCalc == 4)` before the switch. Even better, add a `default` case so that if the user presses 5, he gets a nice error message. E.g.:

  ```
  default:
      std::cout << "Invalid input. Please try again." << std::endl;
      continue;
  ```
- Cool that you have the hang of function pointers. They have a lot of uses. However, you can do without them in this case. Simply remove `FuncChosen` and call the `calc` functions directly inside the switch. Just move the `/* User Input */` section up before the switch and you got all the arguments you need. Calling a function directly is also more efficient than calling it through a pointer (since it is one less layer of indirection).

You've already got some decent C++ code. I hope that the above will get you even further. Just comment if you need some elaboration of my suggestions.

---

**Edit:**: As per you comment, I've added a little extra. If you have access to a C++11 compiler you can:

- Use `std::to_string` instead of `std::ostringstream`. E.g.,

  ```
  double calcSpeed(double distance, double time, string& formula)
  {
      formula = std::to_string(distance) + " / " + std::to_string(time);
      return distance / time;
  }
  ```
- Use [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (also known as [uniform initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization)). E.g., `int chosenCalc{1};` instead of `int chosenCalc = 1;`. The former does not allow narrowing conversions whereas the latter does. This can catch subtle errors.
- Prefer `using` over `typedef`. The former is [more powerful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747810/what-is-the-difference-between-typedef-and-using-in-c11).

Furthermore, you can also take advantage of the following C++14 feature:

- Use `auto` return type deduction. E.g.,

  ```
  auto calcSpeed(double distance, double time, string& formula)
  {
      formula = std::to_string(distance) + " / " + std::to_string(time);
      return distance / time; // Return type is deduced to be double.
  }
  ```

  This is a minor detail in you case. It can be really useful for more complex return types.

Lastly, I want to present a modern alternative to using output parameters. Let me emphasize that it is just an *alternative*. The output parameter approach is fine and which one you chose is completely up to you. The alternative is to return *multiple* values. Let's look at

```
double calcSpeed(double distance, double time, string& formula)
```

which returns a `double` and outputs to a `std::string`. We can instead return a `std::pair` consisting of a `double` and a `std::string`. I.e.,

```
std::pair<double, std::string> calcSpeed(double distance, double time)
{
    auto speed = distance / time; // Auto is deduced to double
    auto formula = std::to_string(distance) + " / " + std::to_string(time); // Auto is deduced to std::string.
    return make_pair(speed, formula);
}
```

Remember to `#include <utility>`. Note that I have also used C++11's `auto` keyword to deduce the type of `speed` and `formula` for us. Like I mentioned before, the `auto` keyword even works for the return type in C++14. So in C++14, we could even just write

```
auto calcSpeed(double distance, double time)
{
    auto speed = distance / time; // Auto is deduced to double
    auto formula = std::to_string(distance) + " / " + std::to_string(time); // Auto is deduced to std::string.
    return make_pair(speed, formula); // Return type is deduced to std::pair<double, std::string>
}
```

You could even let go of the temporary variables and write

```
auto calcSpeed(double distance, double time)
{ return make_pair(distance / time, std::to_string(distance) + " / " + std::to_string(time)); }
```

This is probably as concise as it gets. You can then call `calcSpeed` like this:

```
auto speed_and_formula = calcSpeed(0.5, 0.2); // Returns std::pair<double, std::string>
auto speed = speed_and_formula.first; // This is the double
auto formula = speed_and_formula.second; // This is the string
```

It's a little annoying to write all of this. The C++ committee thought so as well and provided the following simpler method:

```
double speed;
std::string formula;
std::tie(speed, formula) = calcSpeed(0.5, 0.2); // Assigns the first member of the pair to speed and the second member to formula.
```

This should give you a taster of C++11 and C++14.

Comment: You mentioned that I am using C++ 03. I assume I am, but XCode 6 will compile C++ 11 code, are there any improvements I could make/useful alternatives that are new in recent versions of C++. I would like to learn as much as possible of C++, so if there is anything it will be helpful. Thanks for your answer, really helped - have edited program accordingly.

Comment: @exitc0de, I'm glad it helped. I've added a section on C++11 and C++14.

Comment: This is why I am learning C++. Such a fantastic language and so many time saving features you can use. Very powerful. Anyhow, thanks for your revision. REALLY helpful considering I know nothing about more recent versions of C++. I'm pretty sure you can get Xcode to compile C++ 11/14 as well. Is cpp-reference the best resource for learning the newer additions to the language? Might try and find some books I can read as well. Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: @exitc0de, Yes, Xcode 6 can compile both C++11 and C++14. [http://en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com) is my personal go to *reference* for C++ (be it 99/03/11/14/1z). [Heres a good list of C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). I can personally recommend Scott Meyer's "Effective C++", "Effective STL", and the recent "Effective Modern C++". The [videos](https://www.youtube.com/user/CppCon/videos) from CppCon are also an excellent resource.

Comment: I get error: 'auto' return without trailing return type. When swapping double with auto in calcSpeed. Do I need to include something? - It highlights it and everything, Xcode 6 uses clang 6 which compiles C++ 14 as well.

Comment: @exitc0de, Here is a working [code sample](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a882b6499eda09e) using a C++14 compiler. Make sure that you have [enabled C++14 in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952314/xcode-5-1-enable-c14).